# Why are my elements moving when changing position from fixed to static?

Tags: html, css, css-position

so I was building my navbar on my website, and I set every element that it has to `position: fixed`, but I noticed that it wasn't really good looking and I would rather set it to `position: static`, but here is my problem : when I change the position from fixed to static, the position on the screen of my element just changes.

Here is the CSS of one of my elements (a button) :

```
.discord img{
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  left: 3%;
  bottom: 93%;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: 0.3s;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.discord img:hover{
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  left: 3%;
  bottom: 93%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

It acts just as if the `left: 3%` and `bottom: 93%` didn't matter anymore...

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Could you edit and include your HTML as well if poss? You mentioned that from one aspect or another every element on your page is affected but we can only see the styling for your Discord image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML elements are positioned static by default. No need to define that in your CSS, unless you are using a library/framework of some sorts that define the positioning on your element.

An element with `position: fixed;` is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

This means that if you're setting `left: 3%;` and `bottom: 93%;`, the element will be positioned 97% to the left and 7% to the bottom (very close to the top) relative to the viewport - not its parent container, which in this case would be `discord`.

So unless you want the element to be there while you're scrolling the page, don't use `position:fixed;`. If you want your navbar to be set in place and stay there during scrolling, ONLY apply `position: fixed;` to the navbar's parent - the full container containing all your `img`-elements.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/wvpPJPz

**Example snippet that has** `position:fixed;` **on its parent container:**

```css
body {
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

nav.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

nav.static {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

ul {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="fixed">
    <ul>
      <li>fixed</li>
      <li>fixed</li>
      <li>fixed</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <nav class="static">
    <ul>
      <li>static</li>
      <li>static</li>
      <li>static</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```